# Calculus Problem, Slicing a circular cylinder away from axis

Tags: calculus, geometry

Q. Find the volume of the smaller wedge cut from a circular cylinder of radius r by two planes whose line of intersection is a chord at distance b from the axis of the cylinder, if the wedge has thickness c at its thickest point.

Struggling with this question, have done the question when the two planes intersect at the axis, but when it come to integrating at the at a distance from the axis the solution become more complicated.

There is a solution using Trig. I am sure, but it's not asking for that. Feel as if there is a piece of geometry that I am missing which give a simpler solution. If you can help please do, Thanks

[Working so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiZSj.jpg)

Comment: Despite your drawing, I can't picture where the wedge is located. Could you provide a clearer drawing?

Answer (score 1):

The blue rectangle has a width of $2\sqrt{r^2-(b+x)^2}$ and a height 
$\displaystyle h={cx\over r-b}$. The volume of the wedge is thus
$$
\int_0^{r-b}2\sqrt{r^2-(b+x)^2}{cx\over r-b}dx.
$$

[image]

Comment: Hey the concept is correct, although when trying to integrate your solution I run into trouble. Also the previous question (two planes intersecting at the axis) has the problem solved by similar triangle. Thanks for you help

Comment: Make the change of variable $(b+x)/r=\sin\theta$.